# Error when initializing function with typename after typedef in templated class

Tags: c++

The code below does not compile:

```
//in definition
typedef double value_type;

//in implementation
template <typename T>
typename value_type sequence<T>::current( )
{
    return data[used-1];
}
```

Replacing "typename value_type" with "double" causes the code to compile and work as expected. Why can't I use typename value_type in place of double, if I have assigned value_type to be equivalent to double?

Comment: Please show full context: is `value_type` defined within a class definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "*in definition*" means "*in the definition of the `sequence<>` class template*", and "*in implementation*" means "*in the definition of the `current()` member function of the `sequence<>` class template*", then what you have to write is:

```
template <typename T>
typename sequence<T>::value_type sequence<T>::current( )
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return data[used-1];
}
```

Also keep in mind, that unless you are using explicit specializations, the definition of member functions of a class template should be put in the same header that contains the definition of the class template.